# Cocos2d: how to add anchor points to CCSpriteBatchNode

Tags: cocos2d, objective-c, spritesheet

I am doing some tests with animations in Cocos2D using sprite-sheets. The animation works ok except that the anchor-point is in the center. I need to put it in the bottom. With the code below i am not able to add an anchor-point to my sprites, after quite a few tests.

Would someone nice be able to help me with this?

```
-(id) init {

    if((self = [super init])) {

        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"ratHammer.plist" textureFile:@"ratHammer.pvr.ccz"];
        CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"ratHammer.pvr.ccz"];
        [self addChild:spriteSheet];
        NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5 ; ++i) {
            [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ratHammer_anim%d.png", i]]];
    }

    CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];

    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    self.bear = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"ratHammer_anim0.png"];        
    _bear.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                       [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
    [_bear runAction:_walkAction];
    [spriteSheet addChild:_bear];


}
return self;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the anchor point location by setting the `anchorPoint` property of your sprite.

The anchor-point should be given as `CGPoint` and is normalized to `0..1` for both axes. Per default it's at `0.5, 0.5`. The lower left would be `0.0, 0.0`.

To set the anchor point to the lower left, you would use something like this:

```
[spriteSheet setAnchorPoint: ccp(0.0f, 0.0f)];
[_bear setAnchorPoint: ccp(0.0f, 0.0f)];
```

If you need further information, here are the relevant [API docs](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_node.html#ac24fc742eb11ee96207052639224434c).